# Bitteschön vs. Bitte schön: a reversal in meaning?

Tags: colloquial

At [this list](https://www.buzzfeed.com/maximilianzender/jaja) of colloquial German terms, "Bitteschön" is defined as "Bedank dich gefälligst bei mir, du ungehobeltes Arschloch!". When I say "Bitte schön" to thank someone, this is obviously not the intended meaning. My questions are:

1. Does this difference in meaning really exist? Is Buzzfeed stretching the truth?
2. If bitteschön really does imply this negative, is there a difference in the way it is said to differentiate it to "bitte schön"?

Comment: The article is satire!

Comment: It still is a valid question, in my opinion. See my answer.

Comment: Tt means "(t)here you are", or "you're welcome" - that is exactly right! That is how we have used it in Austria, where I grew up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between "bitteschön" and "bitte schön"

There might be a difference from context:

1. "Bitteschön" in response to a "Danke!" would mean what you expect, no negative connotation
2. Giving a "Bitteschön" to a person you helped with no thanks would definitely mean what you found - in any language. Giving a "You're welcome" to someone who didn't thank you for help that was provided would mean the same thing in English.

Comment: Thanks. I have spoken to my German teacher (a native German speaker) and she also believes this, specifically saying "bitte schön" in a response to a missing "danke schön" is a way of getting back at the impoliteness.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the web page is meant as a joke, and the definitions are all but generally valid.

Maybe the confusion arises, because *bitteschön* is written as one word there, and now you seems to think that this *bitteschön* may have a meaning that is different from *bitte schön* written as two words. However, the compounding of *bitte* and *schön* on that web page is simply a spelling error.

Comment: A spelling error? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bitteschoen

Comment: @dessert: that is the noun ("ein Bitteschön"). Anyway, it does not have the meaning "Bedank dich gefälligst bei mir, du ungehobeltes Arschloch!" in any of those spellings.

Comment: FWIW, "Bitte schön" is not "thank you" ("danke schön"), it means "(t)here you are", or "you're welcome", depending on context.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Of course, sorry. When I wrote it, I was already tired. Thank you :-) for pointing out this stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little common sense would help to recognize the article as sitirical.
Still, the question is valid, and “bitte schön” may carry a negative connotation.
It depends on the context, and may often (but not always) be distinguished from its friendly sibling “bitte schön” by the tone in which it is uttered.

The same applies to many (if not all) of the other examples of the buzzfeed article.